# SCCM2012 R2 Software Deployment stuck at "Waiting for Content"

Tags: sccm-2012-r2

I created a package for Adobe CC and I was able to distribute it to my main DP successfully. I then deployed the package to a device collection. All the machines come back as In Progress with a description of "Waiting for content."

I checked one of the machines giving this error and I see

WAS.log:

```
Requesting content POB00013.1, size(KB) 9631117, under context System with priority Low ContentAccess   9/8/2015 11:37:13 AM    5468 (0x155C)
User policy requested with no user credentials. ContentAccess   9/8/2015 11:37:13 AM    5468 (0x155C)
Invalid user.   ContentAccess   9/8/2015 11:37:13 AM    5468 (0x155C)
Submitted CTM job {E28F5F9D-734D-4EE6-ACC0-8CC7FD15FD0F} to download Content POB00013.1 under context System    ContentAccess   9/8/2015 11:37:13 AM    5468 (0x155C)
Successfully created download  request {DA67F1AF-1391-4454-9941-7017BF0E97A4} for content POB00013.1    ContentAccess   9/8/2015 11:37:13 AM    5468 (0x155C)
Location update from CTM for content POB00013.1 and request {DA67F1AF-1391-4454-9941-7017BF0E97A4}  ContentAccess   9/8/2015 11:37:13 AM    6088 (0x17C8)
Download location found 0 - http://POB-SCCM.pob.k12.ny.us/SMS_DP_SMSPKG$/POB00013   ContentAccess   9/8/2015 11:37:13 AM    6088 (0x17C8)
Download request only, ignoring location update ContentAccess   9/8/2015 11:37:13 AM    6088 (0x17C8)
Download started for content POB00013.1 ContentAccess   9/8/2015 11:37:13 AM    5468 (0x155C)
Location update from CTM for content POB00013.1 and request {DA67F1AF-1391-4454-9941-7017BF0E97A4}  ContentAccess   9/8/2015 12:04:11 PM    3336 (0x0D08)
Download location found 0 - http://POB-SCCM.pob.k12.ny.us/SMS_DP_SMSPKG$/POB00013   ContentAccess   9/8/2015 12:04:11 PM    
Download request only, ignoring location update ContentAccess   9/8/2015 12:04:11 PM
```

DataTransferService.log

```
UpdateURLWithTransportSettings(): NEW URL - http://pob-sccm.pob.k12.ny.us:80/SMS_DP_SMSPKG$/POB00013/sccm?/Setup/PRLD4.0en_US/resources/setup.xml   DataTransferService 9/8/2015 11:37:16 AM    6088 (0x17C8)
UpdateURLWithTransportSettings(): OLD URL - http://pob-sccm.pob.k12.ny.us/SMS_DP_SMSPKG$/POB00013/sccm?/Setup/PRLD4.0en_US/resources/updaterinventory.dll   DataTransferService 9/8/2015 11:37:16 AM    6088 (0x17C8)
UpdateURLWithTransportSettings(): NEW URL - http://pob-sccm.pob.k12.ny.us:80/SMS_DP_SMSPKG$/POB00013/sccm?/Setup/PRLD4.0en_US/resources/updaterinventory.dll    DataTransferService 9/8/2015 11:37:16 AM    6088 (0x17C8)
UpdateURLWithTransportSettings(): OLD URL - http://pob-sccm.pob.k12.ny.us/SMS_DP_SMSPKG$/POB00013/sccm?/Setup/PRLD4.0en_US/Set-up.dat   DataTransferService 9/8/2015 11:37:16 AM    6088 (0x17C8)
UpdateURLWithTransportSettings(): NEW URL - http://pob-sccm.pob.k12.ny.us:80/SMS_DP_SMSPKG$/POB00013/sccm?/Setup/PRLD4.0en_US/Set-up.dat    DataTransferService 9/8/2015 11:37:16 AM    6088 (0x17C8)
UpdateURLWithTransportSettings(): OLD URL - http://pob-sccm.pob.k12.ny.us/SMS_DP_SMSPKG$/POB00013/sccm?/setup.exe   DataTransferService 9/8/2015 11:37:16 AM    6088 (0x17C8)
UpdateURLWithTransportSettings(): NEW URL - http://pob-sccm.pob.k12.ny.us:80/SMS_DP_SMSPKG$/POB00013/sccm?/setup.exe    DataTransferService 9/8/2015 11:37:16 AM    6088 (0x17C8)
DTSJob {83F0C7AB-56EA-4ED7-9A03-2B83E3834739} in state 'RetrievedManifest'. DataTransferService 9/8/2015 11:37:17 AM    6088 (0x17C8)
DTSJob {83F0C7AB-56EA-4ED7-9A03-2B83E3834739} in state 'PendingDownload'.   DataTransferService 9/8/2015 11:37:17 AM    5228 (0x146C)
DTSFlag is 0x0000050e   DataTransferService 9/8/2015 11:37:17 AM    5228 (0x146C)
Exclude file list:  DataTransferService 9/8/2015 11:37:17 AM    5228 (0x146C)
Using branch cache option   DataTransferService 9/8/2015 11:37:17 AM    5228 (0x146C)
DTSJob {83F0C7AB-56EA-4ED7-9A03-2B83E3834739} in state 'DownloadingData'.   DataTransferService 9/8/2015 11:37:27 AM    5228 (0x146C)
Enumerating DTS jobs for logged on user 'S-1-5-21-1214440339-73586283-725345543-53323'. DataTransferService 9/8/2015 12:21:09 PM    5640 (0x1608)
Enumeration of DTS jobs for logged on user 'S-1-5-21-1214440339-73586283-725345543-53323' is complete.  DataTransferService 9/8/2015 12:21:09 PM    5640 (0x1608)
Enumerating DTS jobs for helper user 'S-1-5-21-1214440339-73586283-725345543-53323'.    DataTransferService 9/8/2015 12:21:09 PM    5640 (0x1608)
Enumeration of DTS jobs for helper user 'S-1-5-21-1214440339-73586283-725345543-53323' is complete. DataTransferService 9/8/2015 12:21:09 PM    5640 (0x1608)
```

and execmgr.log

```
Policy arrived for parent package POB00013 program Install Adobe CC execmgr 9/8/2015 11:37:13 AM    4392 (0x1128)
Raising client SDK event for class CCM_Program, instance CCM_Program.PackageID="POB00013",ProgramID="Install Adobe CC", actionType 6l, value NULL, user NULL, session 4294967295l, level 0l, verbosity 30l  execmgr 9/8/2015 11:37:13 AM    4392 (0x1128)
Requesting content from CAS for package POB00013 version 1  execmgr 9/8/2015 11:37:13 AM    5468 (0x155C)
Raising event:
[SMS_CodePage(437), SMS_LocaleID(1033)]
instance of SoftDistProgramOfferReceivedEvent
{
    AdvertisementId = "POB2000E";
    ClientID = "GUID:D238EA52-B688-407D-B137-37FAE37159BC";
    DateTime = "20150908153713.490000+000";
    MachineName = "HS-161-01";
    ProcessID = 4600;
    SiteCode = "POB";
    ThreadID = 4392;
};
    execmgr 9/8/2015 11:37:13 AM    4392 (0x1128)
Successfully created a content request handle {DA67F1AF-1391-4454-9941-7017BF0E97A4} for the package POB00013 version 1 execmgr 9/8/2015 11:37:13 AM    5468 (0x155C)
Program Install Adobe CC change to state STATE_ADVANCED_DOWNLOAD content in progress    execmgr 9/8/2015 11:37:13 AM    5468 (0x155C)
Execution Request for advert POB2000E package POB00013 program Install Adobe CC state change from NotExist to AdvancedDownload  execmgr 9/8/2015 11:37:13 AM    5468 (0x155C)
Raising client SDK event for class CCM_Program, instance CCM_Program.PackageID="POB00013",ProgramID="Install Adobe CC", actionType 1l, value , user NULL, session 4294967295l, level 0l, verbosity 30l  execmgr 9/8/2015 11:37:13 AM    5468 (0x155C)
Mandatory execution requested for program Install Adobe CC and advertisement POB2000E   execmgr 9/8/2015 11:37:13 AM    3256 (0x0CB8)
Creating mandatory request for advert POB2000E, program Install Adobe CC, package POB00013  execmgr 9/8/2015 11:37:13 AM    3256 (0x0CB8)
Raising event:
[SMS_CodePage(437), SMS_LocaleID(1033)]
instance of SoftDistWaitingContentEvent
{
    AdvertisementId = "POB2000E";
    ClientID = "GUID:D238EA52-B688-407D-B137-37FAE37159BC";
    DateTime = "20150908153713.521000+000";
    MachineName = "HS-161-01";
    PackageName = "POB00013";
    PackageVersion = "1";
    ProcessID = 4600;
    ProgramName = "Install Adobe CC";
    SiteCode = "POB";
    ThreadID = 3256;
};
    execmgr 9/8/2015 11:37:13 AM    3256 (0x0CB8)
Successfully raised SoftDistWaitingContentEvent event for program Install Adobe CC  execmgr 9/8/2015 11:37:13 AM    3256 (0x0CB8)
Execution Request for advert POB2000E package POB00013 program Install Adobe CC state change from WaitingDependency to WaitingContent   execmgr 9/8/2015 11:37:13 AM    3256 (0x0CB8)
Raising client SDK event for class CCM_Program, instance CCM_Program.PackageID="POB00013",ProgramID="Install Adobe CC", actionType 1l, value , user NULL, session 4294967295l, level 0l, verbosity 30l  execmgr 9/8/2015 11:37:13 AM    3256 (0x0CB8)
Raising client SDK event for class CCM_Program, instance CCM_Program.PackageID="POB00013",ProgramID="Install Adobe CC", actionType 1l, value NULL, user NULL, session 4294967295l, level 0l, verbosity 30l  execmgr 9/8/2015 11:37:13 AM    5152 (0x1420)
Raising client SDK event for class CCM_Program, instance CCM_Program.PackageID="POB00013",ProgramID="Install Adobe CC", actionType 1l, value NULL, user NULL, session 4294967295l, level 0l, verbosity 30l  execmgr 9/8/2015 11:37:13 AM    5468 (0x155C)
Raising client SDK event for class CCM_Program, instance CCM_Program.PackageID="POB00013",ProgramID="Install Adobe CC", actionType 1l, value NULL, user NULL, session 4294967295l, level 0l, verbosity 30l  execmgr 9/8/2015 11:37:16 AM    5228 (0x146C)
Raising client SDK event for class CCM_Program, instance CCM_Program.PackageID="POB00013",ProgramID="Install Adobe CC", actionType 1l, value NULL, user NULL, session 4294967295l, level 0l, verbosity 30l  execmgr 9/8/2015 11:37:17 AM    5468 (0x155C)
Raising client SDK event for class CCM_Program, instance CCM_Program.PackageID="POB00013",ProgramID="Install Adobe CC", actionType 1l, value NULL, user NULL, session 4294967295l, level 0l, verbosity 30l  execmgr 9/8/2015 11:37:27 AM    5856 (0x16E0)
Raising client SDK event for class CCM_Program, instance CCM_Program.PackageID="POB00013",ProgramID="Install Adobe CC", actionType 1l, value NULL, user NULL, session 4294967295l, level 0l, verbosity 30l  execmgr 9/8/2015 11:47:24 AM    4640 (0x1220)
Raising client SDK event for class CCM_Program, instance CCM_Program.PackageID="POB00013",ProgramID="Install Adobe CC", actionType 1l, value NULL, user NULL, session 4294967295l, level 0l, verbosity 30l  execmgr 9/8/2015 11:48:59 AM    4640 (0x1220)
Raising client SDK event for class CCM_Program, instance CCM_Program.PackageID="POB00013",ProgramID="Install Adobe CC", actionType 1l, value NULL, user NULL, session 4294967295l, level 0l, verbosity 30l  execmgr 9/8/2015 11:52:48 AM    6044 (0x179C)
Raising client SDK event for class CCM_Program, instance CCM_Program.PackageID="POB00013",ProgramID="Install Adobe CC", actionType 1l, value NULL, user NULL, session 4294967295l, level 0l, verbosity 30l  execmgr 9/8/2015 11:56:52 AM    6044 (0x179C)
Raising client SDK event for class CCM_Program, instance CCM_Program.PackageID="POB00013",ProgramID="Install Adobe CC", actionType 1l, value NULL, user NULL, session 4294967295l, level 0l, verbosity 30l  execmgr 9/8/2015 12:00:57 PM    4052 (0x0FD4)
Raising client SDK event for class CCM_Program, instance CCM_Program.PackageID="POB00013",ProgramID="Install Adobe CC", actionType 1l, value NULL, user NULL, session 4294967295l, level 0l, verbosity 30l  execmgr 9/8/2015 12:05:05 PM    3336 (0x0D08)
Raising client SDK event for class CCM_Program, instance CCM_Program.PackageID="POB00013",ProgramID="Install Adobe CC", actionType 1l, value NULL, user NULL, session 4294967295l, level 0l, verbosity 30l  execmgr 9/8/2015 12:08:08 PM    3336 (0x0D08)
Raising client SDK event for class CCM_Program, instance CCM_Program.PackageID="POB00013",ProgramID="Install Adobe CC", actionType 1l, value NULL, user NULL, session 4294967295l, level 0l, verbosity 30l  execmgr 9/8/2015 12:11:02 PM    3336 (0x0D08)
Raising client SDK event for class CCM_Program, instance CCM_Program.PackageID="POB00013",ProgramID="Install Adobe CC", actionType 1l, value NULL, user NULL, session 4294967295l, level 0l, verbosity 30l  execmgr 9/8/2015 12:15:14 PM    5064 (0x13C8)
```

If any other information is required please let me know and I will post it. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Monitoring > Distribution Status > Content Status**
Lookup your deployment's content status and verify it is updated. It looks from your logs that the distribution point does not yet have the package.

[image]

Comment: I see the message that the content was successfully transferred package to the DP.

Comment: Does your application/program show like the screenshot?

Comment: Given the size of Creative Cloud, this package isn't going to be properly distributed in a hurry!